# How to specify the side that an element is on in a linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, position, android-linearlayout

I want two buttons side by side with the `Add` button being to the left of `Remove` button. These buttons are programmatically inserted. When only one button is there, it should take up all the space. So far, I have this:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   <include layout="@layout/add_button" />
   <include layout="@layout/remove_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The add button file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addAdditionalColors"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="addColor"
    android:text="@string/addMore"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Remove button file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/removeAdditionalColors"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/remove"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

This works how I want. When one button is removed, the other one spans the whole width of the screen. However, let's say that I have the `Remove` button on the screen and am adding the `Add` button programmatically. It will be added to the right of `Remove` since it is added last. How do I avoid this, preferably in the XML file rather than removing both buttons and adding them in order using Java? Here is the desired position:

[image]

EDIT:
I tried adding indexes when adding the View:

```
buttonLayout.addView(removeButton, 1);
```

and

```
buttonLayout.addView(addButton, 0);
```

The positioning is correct, but for some reason, not all space is filled up, even when I set the width of buttons to match_parent. Please check the video [HERE](https://youtu.be/RhxADBmldUw).

Here is the full code that handles updating the buttons:

```
public void addColor(View view){
            //do stuff
            if(numColors == 4){
                removeView(findViewById(R.id.addAdditionalColors));
                //function above appears to work fine
            }
           else if(numColors == 3){
                final View removeButton = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remove_button, null);
                buttonLayout.addView(removeButton, 1);
            }
    }
    public void removeColor(View view){
        //do stuff
        if(numColors == 3) {
            final View addButton = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_button, null);
            buttonLayout.addView(addButton, 0);
        }
        else if(numColors == 2){
            removeView(findViewById(R.id.removeAdditionalColors));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the end of a LinearLayout:

```
linearLayout.addView(view);
```

To add to the beginning of a LinearLayout:

```
linearLayout.addView(view, 0);
```

The second `addView()` method above takes an index argument, and by passing `0` you're telling it that you want the new view to come "before" all others.

## Edit

The reason your programmatically-added views aren't filling the whole width is that this behavior is a combination of three things:

- "Stretching" in a LinearLayout is enabled by the `layout_weight` attribute
- Your programmatically-inflated views use `null` as the parent argument
- `layout_` attributes are ignored when inflating without a parent

The smallest change you could make to get everything to work would be to change this:

> ```
> final View removeButton = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remove_button, null);
> ```

to this:

```
final View removeButton = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remove_button, buttonLayout, false);
```

By passing `buttonLayout` as the parent, your `layout_weight` attribute will be able to function correctly. You'd have to make a similar change for the "add" button too, of course.